# unpickling spacy model and running into issues with the unpickle_vectors() function

Tags: python, pickle, spacy

tl;dr: when I try to load a spacy PhraseMatcher model from a pickle, I get this error:

`TypeError: unpickle_vectors() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

I'd like to know if it's a me problem, a spacy problem, or a pickle problem, but I really don't know.  Here's what I'm doing, in an iPython notebook if it matters:

```
import pickle
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')
my_phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
# Imagine a bunch of code here stuffing phrases into a spacy PhraseMatcher
# So now I have a phrase matcher absolutely chock-full of phrases
# len(my_phrase_matcher) is something > 300000

with open('whatever.pkl', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_phrase_matcher, f)
```

OK.  At this point, as an exercise in the reproducibility of the parser I'm trying to build without waiting like, a year for the phrase matcher to train every time, I shut down the notebook's kernel and restart it.  I then run the following:

```
import pickle
with open('whatever.pkl') as f:
    my_phrase_matcher_2 = pickle.load(f)
```

and am blessed with the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e22ea248838e> in <module>()
      1 import pickle
      2 with open('whatever.pkl') as f:
----> 3     my_phrase_matcher_2 = pickle.load(f)

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1382 
   1383 def load(file):
-> 1384     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1385 
   1386 def loads(str):

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    862             while 1:
    863                 key = read(1)
--> 864                 dispatch[key](self)
    865         except _Stop, stopinst:
    866             return stopinst.value

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load_reduce(self)
   1137         args = stack.pop()
   1138         func = stack[-1]
-> 1139         value = func(*args)
   1140         stack[-1] = value
   1141     dispatch[REDUCE] = load_reduce

TypeError: unpickle_vectors() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Any insight into what the hell is going on here would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Any luck? I'm getting the same TypeError when loading corpora with textacy (on top of spaCy) after upgrading from textacy 0.5.0 to 0.6.1. Went back to textacy 0.5.0 only to still get the error there. I'm wondering if any changes in spaCy or other dependencies has broken the unpickling in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, so in my case, uninstalling spaCy 2.0.11 and installing spaCy 2.0.8 fixed things for me. Hope it's that simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're specifying the read and write to file in bytes mode:

```
with open('whatever.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_phrase_matcher, f)

...

with open('whatever.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    my_phrase_matcher_2 = pickle.load(f)
```